# Toggle multiple <span> with the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

This shows the hidden numbers on click only on the first occurrence. I am not sure how to make it work if there are multiple  `<span id="number">` within the same text. I wouldn't even mind if they would all show when one of them is clicked. Or they can show independently. Either way.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#number').click(function() {
$(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
});
});
</script>

<span id="number" data-last="1234">5678<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></span>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try classes instead.

Comment: You should look at the details and summary elements in HTML. That is way more semantic than spans. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id in the same document.

> When specified on HTML elements, the `id` attribute value **must be unique** amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character

see [HTML 5 Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id)

I would recommend to use classes instead of ids if you want multiple numbers on a page:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.number').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').text($(this).data('last'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number" data-last="1234">5678<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></div>
<div class="number" data-last="5678">1234<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></div>
<div class="number" data-last="1234">5678<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></div>
<div class="number" data-last="5678">1234<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query DOM node by attribute

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('[data-last]').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
  });
});
</script>

<span id="number" data-last="1234">5678<span>****<span class="showphone">Show</span></span></span>
```

Comment: While this is true, it also doesn't answer the question. You can't legally have multiple elements with the same ID. It **might** work, sometimes with this solution (or even the original) but you never know when / why / how it will stop. For example Chrome 47 and Jquery might allow this, but not in 46 or 48 (and yes, those are old because it doesn't matter the specific versions).

Comment: I am agree with you that id must be unique on the page.